# How to populate value from account into new created opportunity on creation?

Tags: opportunity, picklist, account

We have a custom Pick List field on Account: Payment Terms

The same pick list field (but a different one) is oppty, I need that when creating a new oppty, the value from the account will be populated into the picklist of the oppty.

What are my options to achieve that?

remark: The oppty "payment terms" field should get the default value from the account. However, it can be changed as needed.

Comment: This part: "The same pick list field (but a different one) is oppty" is confusing to me. Is it a custom field called Payment Terms on opportunity and mirrors the values of the field on Account?

Comment: See edit: it should mirror on creation, but can be changed after.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. No matter what someone enters in this field, overwrite it and set the value with a cross object workflow rule or trigger (not recommended).
2. Create a Visualforce page and Controller Extension (of opportunity) for the creation of new opportunities and then override the New button on opportunity (recommended). With this method, updating the fields on the new page is a pain, since they are controlled in your Visualforce page and not on a standard page layout. You can get around this by starting with a simple page to collect simple oppty information, creating the oppty with the Payment Terms populated, and then landing the user on the full edit page of opportunity where they can complete the information needed.

Comment: Just want to understand why the workflow rule is not recommended here. Creating a VF and an extension would be too much effort for this, isn't it?

Comment: The workflow or trigger will essentially reset the value irrespective of what the user entered. I think that's confusing UX but then again, if you never expect your user to enter a value for that field or if the field is hidden on the page layout, then I think the WF is okay.